# Display column name of most recently updated column

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, sql-update

I am wondering if it is possible to display the column name of the most recently updated column in a table.

Example:

```
**Original Record created on 03/20/14:**
Name: John
Height
Weight
Age
Update_date: 03/20/14
Update_Column: Name
```

Then someone comes in and updates the height on 03/22/14:

```
Name: John
Height: 5'9 
Weight
Age
Update_date: 03/22/14
Update_Column: Height
```

And the Update_date and Update_column would change again if someone came in and put a value for age. And so on.

Is this possible?

Also, if the above is possible, would it be possible to display the column name farthest right if a user updated more than one column at the same time?

Example:

```
User updates the below record:
Name: John
Height: 5'9 
Weight
Age
Update_date: 03/22/14
Update_Column: Height
```

And adds in a weight and age at the same time on 03/24/14:

```
Name: John
Height: 5'9
Weight: 150
Age: 31
Update_date: 03/22/14
Update_Column: Height
```

The Update_Column would display Age because it is the farthest to the right. (Thinking of it as you read from left to right, so the column that was last updated would be the one farthest right)

So to sum things up, I need to be able to display Updated_date(which will be the current date when the record is last updated) and Updated_Col (which is the column name of the last column that was updated, and if multiple columns are updated then display the one that a value was updated last in)

Hopefully the examples help to clarify things.

Thanks,
Steven

Comment: You've tagged this for both Oracle and MySQL.  Which database are you actually using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to store those meta data for each row. So you'd need two new columns, the update_date and update_column. Then you can add an `before update` trigger to check which columns are about to change and set the update date.

**update**
Here's an example:

```
delimiter //
create table a (
  id int (10) unsigned auto_increment,
  a int(10),
  b int(10),
  update_date datetime NULL,
  update_column varchar(16) NULL,
  primary key (id)
)//

create trigger bu_a before update on a for each row begin
  set NEW.update_date = NOW();
  set NEW.update_column = NULL;
  -- you need to start with the rightmost column if you want
  -- that matched with the highest priority
  if OLD.b != NEW.b then
    set NEW.update_column = "b";
  elseif OLD.a != NEW.a then
    set NEW.update_column = "a";
  end if;
end //
```

Test:

```
insert into a (id,a,b) values (1,1,1), (2,1,1), (3,1,1), (4,1,1)[
update a set b = 2 where id = 2;
update a set a = 2 where id = 3;
update a set a = 2 where id = 4;
update a set b = 2 where id = 4;
select * from a;
```

Output:

```
ID  A B UPDATE_DATE                  UPDATE_COLUMN
1   1 1 (null)                       (null)
2   1 2 March, 24 2014 23:22:33+0000 b
3   2 1 March, 24 2014 23:22:33+0000 a
4   2 2 March, 24 2014 23:22:33+0000 b
```

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. So if I'm understanding that correctly, the "before update" trigger will basically look at what columns are updated, and then be able to store the column name into the Update_column field. I'm trying to get a better understanding before I go to my DBA with the question. He knows the situation, but maybe this suggestion will help him write the code.

Comment: Well, DBAs tend not to like triggers because it adds more load to the db for the benefit of easier developer job. It depends on the application and the usage if it is better to create a trigger that helps keeping the consistency quite easily or to implement this functionality in the application logic. Anyway the solution above does the trick if you come to an agreement with the DBA :)

Comment: thanks for the example! That helps clarify things a little more. I'll be talking with the DBA tomorrow so hopefully that helps us find a solution.